# Manipulate Solve

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate

I have seen similar questions and answers but it did not help me.
I would like to see effects of three constants in equations resulted from solve command.

conditions are

```
sol = Quiet@Solve[-(27/2) μ (μ^2 - 1/3) == Sin[(π θbar)/2] && -1 < θbar < 1,
    {θbar}, Reals];

MMCX[μ, θbar /. 
   sol, ϵf] := ϵf - (A/c2 (c3 + 
       Sqrt[3]/(2 - Sqrt[3]) (1 - c3) (Sec[(θbar π)/6] - 
          1)) ((Sqrt[((1 + c1^2)/3)]) Cos[(θbar π)/6] + 
       c1 (μ + 1/3 Sin[(θbar π)/6])))^(-(1/n))
```

Parameters are

```
  c1=0.1535; c2 = 720; c3 = 0.9792; A = 1223; n = 0.11;
```

I would like to see effects of C1m c2 and c3 in MMCX when it uses sol at the top

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  sol = Quiet[Solve[(-(27/2))*μ*(μ^2 - 1/3) == Sin[(Pi*θbar)/2] && -1 < θbar < 1,
     {θbar}, Reals]]; 
  MMCX[μ, θbar /. sol, ϵf] == 0,
  {μ, -0.5, 1}, {ϵf, 0, 2.5}], {{c1, 0.1535, "c1"}, 0.1533, 0.1537, 0.0001},
 Initialization :> (MMCX[μ, θbar /. 
      sol, ϵf] := ϵf - ((A/c2)*(c3 + (Sqrt[3]/(2 - Sqrt[3]))*(1 - 
             c3)*(Sec[(θbar*Pi)/6] - 1))*(Sqrt[(1 + c1^2)/3]*
           Cos[(θbar*Pi)/6] + c1*(μ + (1/3)*Sin[(θbar*Pi)/6])))^(-(1/n)))]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I am very new here, so how can I simply copy paste an equation from mathematica to here without converting it to style above?

Comment: I just usually copy the cell and paste it.  You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. -- Sometimes I have to copy in `InputForm`.  (Cell > Convert To > InputForm or Edit > Copy As > Input Text, but I think sometimes they're different.)

Comment: See also: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1442/, http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/, http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1521/

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. You have not defined your functions correctly. Look up [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) in the documentation.
2. You would be repeatedly executing the `Solve` in `Manipulate` once you got the plot to work.  This can be put in the `Initialization` since it does not change as you adjust your variables.
3. You can put the constants `A` and `n` in the `Initialization` and drop the starting values for your variables. *Note that you should not use variables or functions that start in capital letters as you can get conflicts with ones that are system defined.*
4. The variables are not directly visible to the `Manipulate` as they are in the `MMCX` function (*again, bad to start with capital letter*).  One way to fix this is to tell `Manipulate` about them with the `TrackedSymbols` option.

These small changes will get it working for you.

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  MMCX[μ, θbar /. sol, ϵf] == 0, 
   {μ, -0.5, 1}, {ϵf, 0, 2.5}],
 {{c1, 0.15}, 0.0, 0.75, 0.001},
 {{c2, 720}, 700, 750, 1},
 {{c3, 0.975}, 0.960, 1., 0.001},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c1, c2, c3},
 Initialization :> (
   A = 1223; n = 0.11;
   sol = Quiet[
     Solve[(-(27/2))*μ*(μ^2 - 1/3) == 
        Sin[(Pi*θbar)/2] && -1 < θbar < 
        1, {θbar}, Reals]];
   MMCX[μ_, θbar_, ϵf_] :=
    ϵf - ((A/c2)*(c3 + (Sqrt[3]/(2 - Sqrt[3]))*(1 - c3)
           *(Sec[(θbar*Pi)/6] - 1))*(Sqrt[(1 + c1^2)/3]
           *Cos[(θbar*Pi)/6] + 
          c1*(μ + (1/3)*Sin[(θbar*Pi)/6])))^(-(1/n)))]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I see where I was wrong.